# Reduce using loop for redundant SQL in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, for-in-loop

```
FOR k IN (SELECT UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME ,UC.TABLE_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS UC
   INNER JOIN MIG_TABLE_LIST MIG ON UC.TABLE_NAME = MIG.TABLE_NAME
   WHERE UC.TABLE_NAME = MIG.TABLE_NAME AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('R', 'C', 'U')) LOOP
   l_sql := 'ALTER TABLE '||k.TABLE_NAME||' DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||k.CONSTRAINT_NAME||' CASCADE';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
END LOOP;
```

Above for..in loop, iterate table name in `MIG_TABLE_LIST`and disable all the corresponding constraints. The same loop is also used to enable constraint, how if I can get rid of using loop for constraint enabled?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it without looping. Do you think you need to? If so, why?

Comment: I was thinking if there's a way to improve performance of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for disable *enabled* you need to use something like

```
FOR k IN (SELECT UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME ,UC.TABLE_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS UC
   INNER JOIN MIG_TABLE_LIST MIG ON UC.TABLE_NAME = MIG.TABLE_NAME
   WHERE UC.TABLE_NAME = MIG.TABLE_NAME AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('R', 'C', 'U') AND UC.STATUS='ENABLED') 
LOOP
   l_sql := 'ALTER TABLE '||k.TABLE_NAME||' DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||k.CONSTRAINT_NAME||' CASCADE';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
END LOOP;
```

and for enable *disabled* constraints

```
FOR k IN (SELECT UC.CONSTRAINT_NAME ,UC.TABLE_NAME FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS UC
   INNER JOIN MIG_TABLE_LIST MIG ON UC.TABLE_NAME = MIG.TABLE_NAME
   WHERE UC.TABLE_NAME = MIG.TABLE_NAME AND UC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('R', 'C', 'U') AND UC.STATUS='DISABLED') 
LOOP
   l_sql := 'ALTER TABLE '||k.TABLE_NAME||' ENABLE CONSTRAINT '||k.CONSTRAINT_NAME||' CASCADE';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: any impact if disable a _disabled_ constraint or enable an  _enabled_ constraint again?

Comment: As you see first query selects only *enabled* constraints. So, if some constraint are *disabled* they will not be selected.

Answer (score 0):

How to get rid of a loop? Instead of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. Copy/paste the result into a file.

- run it to disable constraints
- use your editor's *Search & Replace* functionality and replace `DISABLE` with `ENABLE`, and run the script again.

Comment: never mind, i will remain the loop, your suggestion is fine but i need it to be automate.